# Games Won't run after resetting Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gaming

So I installed windows 10 at first and it worked fine and I even finished a game on it, but for some reasons I needed to reset my windows and now no game will run (after reinstalling!)! nothing! Not even a black window will come up!
This is getting really frustrating, I tried everything I could, I made a new account and tried on that, run system file checker, got all the updates, installed all the drivers, set my laptop to high performance, installed directX 11 and still nothing! Any help at all would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: You need to install those programs again.  You can't "install" DirectX on  Windows 10, it is built in, there hasn't been an install for DirectX since DX 9 anyways.

Comment: I know enough to install softwares and games again after resetting!!! for your information "after installing" the games won't run!

Comment: When you say they don't run, what happens exactly, they have to be doing something.

Comment: Nothing! That's my problem! Nothing appears at all! For 1 or 2 seconds the cursor changes to loading and thats it! Nothing pops up or opens!

Comment: How exactly did you install DX11 on Windows 10 by the way?

Comment: Fount the installation somewhere through searching, don't exactly remember where it was.

Comment: You installed DX9 or DX11.  I ask because there isn't a DX11 installer, and even if there was, DX12 is integrated into Windows 10 so installing DX11 might be the reason for the odd behavior.  can you provide us a dxdiag log for good measure?

Comment: My directX version is 11.3 based on DirectX Diagnostic Tool

Comment: I asked for the log file itself.  I asked to know which version you installed.  I asked for this information because there are technical statements that I believe are inaccurate.  I still have not been provided the answers to those questions/requests.  I would not be asking if they were not important.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29008/discussion-between-amen-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

Resetting Windows 10 removes all installed software that didn't come already installed.

See [Recovery options in Windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options) for more information about what "Reset" does.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be deleted or be replaced as a comment

Comment: The problem is that I cannot add comments, since I don't have required 50 points. So I can either try to help via response or do nothing.

Comment: And furthermore, it is an answer, just try to read the info in the link - when you reset Win 10, your programs are gone. You cry for help, but are incapable of providing any usable info at all.

Comment: @Ascorti - A link only answer isn't acceptable.  *You being unable to post a comment isn't a valid reason to post a comment as an answer.*  You do have an option, edit your current answer, so it contain the relevant information from the link.

Answer (score -1):

If your games are supported by old safedisc DRM then, it will not run in windows10. It will be block by windows 10 because, it will be thought as having malware.

Comment: I can't even start the game I finished on windows 10 before resetting, the problem is something else!

Comment: Which proves once and for all DRM is a malware.  Anyway, if one wants to play games, one should make sure everything needed by them is installed. List here: https://xaeus.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/how-to-make-games-actually-work-en/